# Messages in Outlook email body is getting overwritten

Tags: python, email, outlook

I want the script to check if a list (suspended_stat) has items in it and write a message in the outlook body and then check if another list (outlook_stat_final) has items in it and then write the message in the outlook body.
Problem is only last mailbody.item (TEXT_2) shows up in the email body, and it seems like suspended_stat messages are getting overwritten. How to make sure messages are not overwritten?

```
if suspended_stat:  
    
    mail_item.Body = greet  + msg  + "\n".join(suspended_stat)  + '\t\n \t\n' "text_1. \t\n \t\n" 
else:
    
    mail_item.Body = greet  + "No activity detected" '\t\n \t\n'

if outlook_stat_final:
    mail_item.Body= "\n".join(outlook_stat_final) + "\t\n \t\n" + signature
else:
    mail_item.Body = "TEXT_2. \t\n\t\n"  + signature
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly is because you overwrite the message in the bottom if... create another variable for bottom message or concat the bottom message, like: `mail_item.Body += ...`

Try:

```
if suspended_stat:
    mail_item.Body = greet  + msg  + "\n".join(suspended_stat)  + '\t\n \t\n' "text_1. \t\n \t\n" 
else:
    mail_item.Body = greet  + "No activity detected" '\t\n \t\n'

if outlook_stat_final:
    mail_item.Body += "\n".join(outlook_stat_final) + "\t\n \t\n" + signature
else:
    mail_item.Body += "TEXT_2. \t\n\t\n"  + signature
```